# Sequence detector which detects sequences 100 and 111

Tags: digital-logic, state-machines, sequence-detector

I need to design a pattern detector that recognizes 100 and 111 bit patterns, even overlapping ones. I drew the state diagram as shown in the image

[image]

and created the related table

[image]

Could you tell me if it is correct? I also wanted to ask if the number of states is related to the number of bits (in this case the sequences are 3 bits, but could be for example 5) or if it comes from other data.

Comment: Looks good to me. Yes, the number of states is related to the length of the pattern(s) and the number of patterns, but it also depends on how much overlap there is among different patterns.

Comment: I agree. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIvU9.png) is what I get. Looks the same.

Comment: Ok thanks @periblepsis,  now if I wanted to build a sequence detector that detects a 4 bit sequence (for example 1011) would 4 states be enough as in the example I developed here https://postimg.cc/7JVD5jTY ? Why in this case if we have 4 bits and not 3 as in the previous exercise does the number of states not change? I'm stuck on this concept.

Comment: @Dave Tweed No, overlap is not important. Design the logic for a single occurrence and you will find them all. For more detail, please check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case, I recommend you to use a serial-in parallel-out register. With it you would only need to connect the serial input to the data stream, connect the shift clock to the same clock your data uses to change state and then using the first n bits of the parallel output to apply your logic.

As data is being inputted serially, every cell in the shift register is being replaced by the next one. As the logic would only check three consecutive bits it would always find all occurrences, without caring about them being overlapped.

There are other ways, like designing an automat as you are already doing; but that may not be necessary as the logic you describe does not seem to alter the states of the fsm and just generates the output (therefore doing exactly the same).

In your case with your 3-bit sequence equation would be:

Result = Bit_2 AND (Bit_1 XNOR Bit_0)

Why this equation? Assuming you need an active high output (result is true if conditions met) you will always require the higher bit to be 1. About the other two, you don't care about the exact value of them but both must be equal. Gate XOR always returns true if different, therefore using its complementary (XNOR) we will obtain a true if its inputs are equal.

To complement this wall of text, I append this schematic for refference:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYe8da.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answering to your last comment in your question: if you wanted to expand the circuit and check for more bits, more stages of the shift register shall be used and logic modified. The number of stages you would be using is the number of bits of your pattern minus one, which is taken directly from the input.

I hope it helps

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to optimize. The shift register technique is certainly straightforward to design, and for short patterns may use the same number of FFs as the type of state machine the OP is asking about. But for longer patterns, it requires more FFs than the state machine.

Comment: @DaveTweed I disagree. Remember that the system should detect overlapping patterns. If you implemented the finite state machine in a way that stored a bit to represent if the sequence is correct to that point without storing the sequence per se, you would need another flip flop for the next recognized pattern, and if the pattern to be found is large enough you would need a flip flop for each of the overlapped occurrences. For this reason I think it is important to store it and treat it as it comes.

Comment: No, you don't need a FF for each occurrence, you need a state. The number of states grows roughly linearly with the number and the length of the patterns, but the number of FFs only grows logarithmically. With your technique, the number of FFs grows linearly with the length of the pattern(s) -- and the number of states grows exponentially -- regardless of anything else.

Comment: (1) Your point is good but I don't share it. As you said, the number of states duplicates with each bit added. You could do it with a one bit state to represent correctness of the input sequence, and a n bit value to represent the current step; outputs being correctness (only set once the pattern has been completely processed), the expected value of the input to compare with the actual value and next state. That would keep the number of state bits pretty low for long sequences.

Comment: (2) There is, however a problem with this implementation. What you say about logarithmic growing is true, but only when events are dependent among them. In this case they are completely independent, the finite-state-machine not only needs to know if the alredy inputted pattern is correct, but also where. This implementation is good, but will not find overlapped patterns.

Comment: (3) I'll update my answer later to reflect this exchange. Maybe I'm not explaining myself as well as I think I am.

Comment: You may need to brush up on [NFAs and DFAs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton), which is the theory behind the kind of state machine that the OP and I are talking about. This was part of my education some 45 years ago; I'm not sure that modern students get the same level of exposure.

Comment: I am aware of them. Please, would you explain how would you do it?

Comment: See the writeup that I did some time ago [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/161868/11683). Also [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/414588/11683).

Comment: Now I see what you were meaning. I did not fully understand you. Note that I'll improve my answer later on.